# Debug iOS 6+7 Mobile Safari using the Chrome DevTools

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

iOS 6 comes with built-in support for remote debugging ([1 minute screencast](http://www.screenr.com/GYZ8)). It plays nice with the new Safari Web Inspector which seems to be a 1 year old fork of WebKit Inspector. It misses some features such JS editing and WebSocket frames inspection.

> Safari's Web inspector does use the WebKit remote debugging protocol. However, Safari does not use TCP/HTTP as a transport layer, thus making it incompatible with Chrome.

[says Timothy Hatcher (aka Xenon), Apple employe](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/158126)

- What does Safari use for transport layer?
- Can I make a proxy from this mysterious transport layer to HTTP to make it work with Chrome DevTools?

Comment: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/158126

Comment: the devforums.apple.com link posted above doesn't work.

Comment: It does work but you have to log in.

Comment: It didn't work for me, either, even after logging in with my dev account. I get an "error occurred" page.

Comment: For those without login the answer says: "Safari's Web inspector does use the WebKit remote debugging protocol. However, Safari does not use TCP/HTTP as a transport layer, thus making it incompatible with Chrome."

Comment: Yep, the link is a bad link.  Thanks to @Erik for posting the info.

Comment: More details from the link: a proxy written by Google: https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The [**iOS WebKit Debug Proxy**](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy) project enables this.

[image: screenshot]

To get started, install with homebrew:

```
brew install ios-webkit-debug-proxy
```

Run the simulator (if running simulator):

```
SIM_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
  "$SIM_DIR/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone Simulator" \
  -SimulateApplication \
  $SIM_DIR/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/Applications/MobileSafari.app/MobileSafari
```

Run the proxy:

```
ios_webkit_debug_proxy
```

#### Check for errors

Look on the device for an error message:

> Could not connect to lockdownd. Exiting.: No such file or directory. Unable to attach  inspector ios_webkit_debug_proxy

Then check the device for a prompt [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPaqX.png) (iOS 7 example: )

> Trust the currently connected computer?

Choose "Trust" and try rerunning the proxy:

```
ios_webkit_debug_proxy
```

#### Open default devtools

Then open `http://localhost:9221`

The DevTools are, by default, an older version (from Chrome 18 circa March 2012).

#### Try modern devtools

Due to [protocol](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/debugger-protocol) changes, parts the modern DevTools frontend may not work completely. You can try by opening

```
chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?ws=localhost:9222/devtools/pag‌​e/2
```

where the `port` and `page` values are the values you're seeing from `http://localhost:9221`. Again, this may indeed be buggy.

Read more docs at the [ios-webkit-debug-proxy project page](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy).

---

**Update:** This works with [iOS7 as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxEB0.png). **Update**: Added fresh devtools frontend instructions via [patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960588/patrick).. **Update**: Changed devtools.html to inspector.html [for Chrome 45](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=529818), and the new `ws` hack via Scheintod.

Comment: Please guys let me know if there's a Windows version for it. Tks!

Comment: I use chromes current devtools, but use chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools.html?host=localhost:9222&page=1 - making sure the localhost:port&page=# is the same as the one created for you when you go through port 2221

Comment: Could not connect to lockdownd. Exiting.: No such file or directory
Unable to attach 66c5cb9cc4d362b2aecf208axxxxxxxxxxxxx inspector

Comment: @ed1nh0 just finished win32 port https://github.com/artygus/ios-webkit-debug-proxy-win32

Comment: @artygus Looks great except I don't see any styles.

Comment: @pppeater yeah, works best with iOS6.. the tool has some issues with iOS7, i suggest using the latest devtools (only for iOS7) bundled with Chrome - it solves some issues. but generally "hackish" rules breaks styles tab

Comment: @artygus I tried with the last version of Chrome before the switch to Blink (not sure if it actually matters) and I can see styles: https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/static/27.0.1453.116/devtools.html?host=localhost:9222&page=2

Comment: @pppeater it's related to https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy/issues/20 i guess

Comment: @NVI I still can not debug javascript function. Can I do it?

Comment: @sahara108 I have not used it but I found this page linked from weinre: http://lexandera.com/aardwolf/

Comment: For those waiting for Windows support, there's another option in the meantime: http://autumnator.wordpress.com/2014/06/13/debugging-mobile-and-tablet-websites-on-ios-on-windows-or-locally-on-device/

Comment: I only got this to work via `ws` parameter. You can get a webservice url if you call `localhost:9222/json` and then append this like so: `chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools.html?ws=localhost:9222/devtools/page/2`

Comment: Can I use for this tool for debugging iOS apps (i.e: sencha touch). Can anyone suggest me please ? Or any such tool which help in debugging iOS apps (hybrid apps) by using chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://github.com/andydavies/node-iosdriver,

> Safari uses the same debugging commands as Chrome but wrapped as binary plists over RPC rather than JSON over websockets.

So, yes, it would possible to write a proxy.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280536/how-to-connect-to-iphones-webkit-debugger) by looking at what TCP connections Safari was making while connected to the MobileSafari inspector, seeing that it was connected to a process called `webinspectord` and Googling that:

```
# pgrep -lf /Applications/Safari.app
33170 /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari -psn_0_21144617
# lsof -p 33170 | grep TCP
Safari  33170 ryan   16u    IPv6 0x799d5f43b472a241       0t0      TCP localhost:54892->localhost:27753 (ESTABLISHED)
# lsof -i :27753
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
launchd     371 ryan   42u  IPv6 0x799d5f43b472aa01      0t0  TCP localhost:27753 (LISTEN)
Safari    33170 ryan   16u  IPv6 0x799d5f43b472a241      0t0  TCP localhost:54892->localhost:27753 (ESTABLISHED)
webinspec 33182 ryan    6u  IPv6 0x799d5f43b472aa01      0t0  TCP localhost:27753 (LISTEN)
webinspec 33182 ryan    7u  IPv6 0x799d5f43b181a621      0t0  TCP localhost:27753->localhost:54892 (ESTABLISHED)
# ps p 33182
  PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
33182   ??  S      0:00.28 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/libexec/webinspectord
```

Comment: I use the ios-webkit-debug-proxy now and have stopped working on node-iosdriver