# Debugging iOS7 Safari CSS issues with web inspector

Tags: ios7, safari-web-inspector

I followed the steps to set up debugging webpage on iOS. It worked. However I see an issue with the inspector - it doesn't let me check the DOM and corresponding CSS. Anyone else has this issue? (Exact same issue when debugging using the simulator.)

Screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/E4fxPQwk14

Resource: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html

Thanks!

UPDATE: WebKit nightly works. Thank you Timothy Hatcher!

Comment: the need of the lighting cable makes this really annoying...

Comment: Fortunately, not all devices with iOS7 require a Lightning cable.

Comment: It have happened on an iOS7 simulator too, I couldn't expand a DOM element, although I could still work in console window.

Comment: Please mark Timothy Hatcher's answer as correct.

Comment: Just to expand on this, the problem happens as soon as you click on the 'style' {} icon. If you are on one of the other tabs (e.g. 'Node' <>), you can still expand the DOM element.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to use a WebKit nightly, Safari 6.1 or Mavericks to use Web Inspector with iOS 7.

Comment: Safari 6.1 doesn't seem to be able to breakpoint a js app on the iPhone.

Comment: OS X 10.7 n not supporter. Nightly builds of WebKit are not supported on OS X 10.7 at this time.

Comment: In case it helps someone: It took me a while to find a nightly that worked on my OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion). Finally I'm using this one successfully: http://builds.nightly.webkit.org/files/trunk/mac/WebKit-SVN-r163565.dmg

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to Mavericks, You can also use Chrome devtools via proxy.

[Debug iOS 6+7 Mobile Safari using the Chrome DevTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361822/debug-ios-67-mobile-safari-using-the-chrome-devtools)

Comment: ... or, if you subscribe, [Adobe Edge Inspect](http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/)