# Safari Web Inspector doesn't debug JavaScript in iOS 7 Simulator

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, ios-simulator, web-inspector

I have `Safari` 6.0.5 (8536.30.1) and `WebKit` nightly (8536.30.1, 538+) and I'm trying to debug a website in `iOS 7` iPad simulator ( `XCode` `Version 5.0` (5A1413). 
I choose `Develop`->`iPad simulator` in `Safari`, Web Inspector starts showing me the website's resources and `DOM`, and I enable few breakpoints in `JavaScript` file of the website. Then I perform something with the site to reach my breakpoints.
 The site freezes, as if it reached the breakpoint but Web Inspector doesn't show that it reached anything and doesn't show any variables. I even do not see the variables pane.
 What am I doing wrong?

Comment: iOS WebKit debug proxy saved my day! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361822/debug-ios-67-mobile-safari-using-the-chrome-devtools

Comment: My web inspector is simply crashing when trying to view the JS files in there.

Comment: sometimes i run the `location.reload()` command on console, it'll be work.

Comment: As a web developer, you should use Firefox.

Comment: @PHPglue you can only inspect website on iDevices from Safari. So using Firefox isn't going to help.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Update your browser and secondly open Firefox Inspector and then run your application.